# Create a variable href for html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have the task to create a website singlehandedly and it should be somehow secure.
So normally you would make an href to get images or a new html.
Until now those are static. So if you would make an href="Images/001.png" you would get it,
even if you would not have logged in.

My solution would be a random generated code that together with the session/login creates a path
to the image.
I use Node.js together with express and would like to know what the most elegant way to do this would be.
At the time I programmed a File reader that searches for hrefs and overwrites them with the random generated code. After this the new formed html is returned to the client.

Comment: Does your images stored in the server side ?

Comment: That sounds like a massive amount of effort for a not-very-secure result. Is there a reason you aren't just using the data in the session to determine if they should access the resource?

Comment: the images are stored at the server side.

Comment: @Quentin my boss does not want that anyone who those have access receives a static href that he than in return can be assumed.
like "images/titel/001.png" most likely has "images/titel/002.png".
Every href should be new, so that even in case that somebody saves href can't excess the data.

Comment: Why would knowing that `images/titel/002.png` exist be a problem? Just issue a 403 Forbidden header if it is requested by someone who doesn't have authorisation to access it.

Comment: Could it be really that simpel?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.